# How can I get custom field value from popup selected index features if field visibility is false? (arcgis-js-api 4.12)

Tags: angular9, arcgis-js-api

I create a feature layer from external service(JSON data). All the fields of the feature layer display in the popup. There is one custom field i.e. for eg 'Test_id' which has a unique value for each feature(not ObjectId). When I open any popup I get a selected index popup feature and from that feature/attributes, I fetch the 'Test_id' field value to perform some action. If I set field visibility false then in popup features I am not getting that field but I want that field to perform some logic and at the same time I want that field is not displayed in the popup.

**Issues**: If I set field visibility false then in popup features I am not getting that field.

**Question**: How can I get custom field value from popup selected index features if field visibility is false? If visibility is true then how to display none for that field in the popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you refer to the field visibility when publishing the service. If you don't make it visible in the service, you can not retrieve it, so this is not the solution.

The solution is just to exclude from the fieldinfos of the popup, just that.

[ArcGIS API - PopupTemplate fieldInfos](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-PopupTemplate.html#fieldInfos)

Update:

The fields that the feature will carry to the popup are set by the `outFields` property. This field is necessary if the content of the popup is a function of a promise.

You can indicate to carry all fields like this `outFields=['*']`, and after try be more specific.

Comment: field visibility I refer to in popup fieldinfos, not in service. So that's why I asked How can I get field value from popup selected index features if field visibility is false in the popup fieldinfos? I set visibility true in popup fieldinfos to get that field value but the requirement is that field should not display in the popup.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand you correctly .. Are you using `FieldsContent` as content for the layer `popupTemplate`?, if not, what type are you using? .. Where do you need to use `Test_id` field?

Comment: sample code for popupTemplate: 'popupTemplate': {
                'title': layerTitle,
                'content': [{
                  'type': 'fields',
                  'fieldInfos': popUpFieldsArray
                }],. Now when I opened popup i want that field value in mapView.popup.features[mapView.popup.selectedFeatureIndex]

Comment: Thanks for response. By setting content my issue resolved.

Comment: One more quick question if popup is in collapse mode and on click of title bar popup content is visible and map pan to center. Why map pan and can we stop that.

Comment: Sorry the delay .. By default it should not pan or zoom to feature when you click on the popup title .. You probably have some custom action

Comment: thanks for response but i didn't added any custom action for title bar.